# How to handle initialization of Windows.Forms in a different thread/task while the form is not shown?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, splash-screen

I have a C# .NET Framework 4.7 application, within which the main form takes some time to load (database queries, etc.).

To inform the user that the application is running and loading, I have implemented a splash screen.

However, I could not get managed to make the MainForm initialization (database queries, etc.) work.

If I put the initialization code into the MainForm constructor, and put `mainForm = new MainForm()` into the main thread/task, the splash screen freezes as there is no DoEvent() since the operating is synchronous.

If I put the initialization code into an MainForm method, and put `mainForm = new MainForm()` as shown below, and put the initialization as shown below, I will end up with `InvalidOperationException`s as I try to access components which are within another thread/task.

When I try to workaround this exceptions using `Invoke` in a task (as shown below), I end up with another `InvalidOperationException` complaining about `Invoke` cannot be called when the form is not shown (window handle not created). I tried to create the window handle before I call `Invoke`, but got the same exception, as the form must be shown in order to `Invoke` anything.

How to initializes MainForm within a separate thread/task so multiple initialization tasks can happen in parallel within the Main function?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

internal static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    private static int Main()
    {
        // Display the splash screen.
        var splashScreen = new SplashScreenForm()
        {
            ApplicationTitle = Program.Information.EntryAssembly.Title,
            ApplicationVersionInformation = string.Format("Version {0} ({1})", Program.Information.EntryAssembly.InformationalVersion, Program.Information.EntryAssembly.Configuration),
            Copyright = Program.Information.EntryAssembly.Copyright
        };
        splashScreen.Show();

        var initTasks = new List<Task>();
        var mainForm = new MainForm();

        // Load main form.
        {
            var initTask = new Task(() => { mainForm.Initialize(); });
            initTasks.Add(initTask);
            initTask.Start();
        }

        // Some other initialization tasks, that are NOT related to MainForm.
        {
            var initTask = new Task(() => { Console.WriteLine("Foo Bar") });
            initTasks.Add(initTask);
            initTask.Start();
        }

        // Wait until all initialization tasks are done.
        while (initTasks.Any((Task t) => { return !Convert.ToBoolean(t.IsCanceled | t.IsFaulted | t.IsCompleted); }))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        // Check for failed initialization tasks.
        if (initTasks.Any((Task t) => { return Convert.ToBoolean(t.IsCanceled | t.IsFaulted); }))
        {
            var exes = new List<Exception>();
            foreach (var t in initTasks.FindAll((Task t) => { return Convert.ToBoolean(t.IsCanceled | t.IsFaulted); }))
            {
                exes.Add(t.Exception);
            }
            throw new AggregateException("Some main initialization tasks have failed.", exes.ToArray());
        }

        // Cleanup tasks.
        initTasks.ForEach((Task t) => { t.Dispose(); });
        initTasks.Clear();
        splashScreen.Close();
        splashScreen.Dispose();

        Application.Run(mainForm);
        Application.Exit();
        Application.DoEvents();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would package your initialisation code up into some background worker of the splash screen. Then change the view. Not sure how a forms app behaves without running an application. Doesn't that setup the message pump?

Comment: Creating a window on a worker thread is rocket-science that is extremely difficult to get right.  Especially so in Winforms, deadlock is a very common outcome and it can strike long after the 'splash screen' was destroyed.   Too many controls use the UserPreferenceChanged event.  You need to do this the other way around, it is the data retrieval that is slow and that can easily be spun off on a worker thread.  Further enhance by considering that no user ever likes to have to plow through thousands of rows of data.

Comment: You should never ever try to create or interact with a UI element from a non-UI thread. You should also never ever call `Application.DoEvents()` - that's only in the framework for backward compatibility with VB6.

Comment: You should be pushing the "(database queries, etc.)" onto a different thread, not the UI.

Comment: Did I mention that `Application.DoEvents()` was a bad evil thing?

Comment: Cold tasks are a bad idea too. Tasks aren't threads that need a `.Start()` to start running. `Task.Run()` is enough. They don't need polling to check if they're running. There's no need to call `Application.DoEvents()` either. If you really have stuff that needs to be done in the background, use `await Task.Run(thatStuff)` to do it before displaying the main form, eg right after you display the splash screen.

Comment: In this case, the stuff that should be run in the background is the code that *isn't* posted in the question - everything that doesn't have to do with the forms themselves.